# Usando o navigation condicionalmente react-native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-navigation

Estou enviando dados para uma API e ao receber tudo ok gostaria que direcionasse o usuário para outra página, porém, se der algum erro, exiba um modal de erro e um HelpText de baixo dos inputs e continue na mesma página. Tentei de duas formas:

1. Usando o navigate dentro da chamada axios, caso o retorno dê ok

```
    axios.post(URL, data).then((res) => {
      if (res.data.data) {
        console.log(res.data.message);
        setModalText("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");
        navigation.navigate("Login");
        setSucessIcon(true);

      }
      if (res.data.error) {
        console.log(res.data.error);
        setModalText(res.data.error);
        setErrorIcon(true);
      }
    });

    setModalVisible(true); // aqui setta o modal em qualquer if, para que se apareça um erro mostre no modal, e se for efetuado o registro apareça a mensagem de sucesso no modal
  };
```

Nesse primeiro caso, mesmo que dê erro o navigation acontece..

2.Tentei também usando uma função ao clicar no botão..

```
const efetuandoLogin = () => {
    if ( chave || senha || confirmSenha === "" ) {
      setHelpText(true);
    } else {
      register();
      navigation.navigate("Login");
    }
  }
```

Só que dessa vez não redireciona e nem chama o Register(chamada axios)
Alguém sabe me dizer o porquê disso??

Answer (score 0):

o axios tem o metodo catch em caso de erro pela API. Então tenta dessa forma:

```
axios.post(URL, data).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data.message);
    setModalText("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");
    navigation.navigate("Login");
    setSucessIcon(true);      
}).catch((error) => {
    setModalText(res.data.error);
    setErrorIcon(true);
});
```

Documentação axios: https://axios-http.com/ptbr/docs/example

Comment: Obg pela resposta! Estou tentando usando o catch mas no modal o texto não aparece e também direciona para o login.. Parece que não está chegando na condição. Tb vem um aviso ao usar o navigation dentro do axios. "Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component." Sabe qual outro jeito posso fazer isso? Pq com uma função de if/else no onPress também não chega na condição..